# How to include !important in jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to add !important in the css attribute using jQuery like

```
$("tabs").css('height','650px;!important');
```

but !important has no effect. How to include !important in jquery?

Comment: Can you try without the semicolon between the value and !important?

Comment: Marc W's answer is the answer. You don't need !important.

Comment: Though Marc W's Answer is technically right answer, klokop's answer works

Answer (score 166, accepted):

Apparently it's possible to do this in jQuery:

```
$("#tabs").css("cssText", "height: 650px !important;");
```

Src: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/2066

Comment: Although, you can do $(elem).css('cssText', $(elem).css('cssText') + "your new css") right? ;)

Comment: What is cssText here?

Comment: @Diffy, cssText is the 'cssText' property of the 'style' property. (ie, element.style.cssText)

Comment: I had to set both height and width using this method, you have to write it as a one liner. Example `$('img').css('cssText', "max-width: " +ui.value + 'px !important;' + "max-height: "+ui.value + 'px !important;');`

Comment: @Juan Although it will bring you also non inline styles. You will end up with a newspaper of CSS.

Comment: hah, the comments here seem to be worth upvoting.. @ShadiNamrouti.. well said..every one- as said..  I did end up with _NewsPaper_ of _CSS_ .. was playing with some jquery-ui ..

Answer (score 7):

I solved this problem with:

```
inputObj.css('cssText', inputObj.attr('style')+'padding-left: ' + (width + 5) + 'px !IMPORTANT;');
```

So no inline-Style is lost, an the last overrides the first

Answer (score 6):

It is also possible to add more important properties:

`inputObj.attr('style', 'color:black !important; background-color:#428bca !important;');`

Answer (score 6):

```
var tabsHeight = 650;

$("tabs").attr('style', 'height: '+ tabsHeight +'px !important');
```

OR

```
#CSS
.myclass{height:650px !important;}
```

then

```
$("tabs").addClass("myclass");
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need to have jquery use !important for more than one item, this is how you would do it.

e.g. set an `img` tags max-width and max-height to 500px each

```
$('img').css('cssText', "max-width: 500px !important;' + "max-height: 500px !important;');
```

Answer (score 2):

For those times when you need to use jquery to set !important properties, here is a plugin I build that will allow you to do so.

```
$.fn.important = function(key, value) {
    var q = Object.assign({}, this.style)
    q[key] = `${value} !important`;
    $(this).css("cssText", Object.entries(q).filter(x => x[1]).map(([k, v]) => (`${k}: ${v}`)).join(';'));
};

$('div').important('color', 'red');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to override css that has !important rules in it, for instance, in a case I ran into recently, overriding a wordpress theme required !important scss rules to break the theme, but since I was transpiling my code with webpack and (I assume this is why --)my css came along in the chain after the transpiled javascript, you can add a separate class rule in your stylesheet that overrides the first !important rule in the cascade, and toggle the heavier-weighted class rather than adjusting css dynamically. Just a thought.

Answer (score -3):

You don't need `!important` when modifying CSS with jQuery since it modifies the `style` attribute on the elements in the DOM directly. `!important` is only needed in stylesheets to disallow a particular style rule from being overridden at a lower level. Modifying `style` directly *is* the lowest level you can go, so `!important` has no meaning.

Comment: Unless you want to override an existing !important rule…

Comment: Yeah: if there’s an `!important` in the stylesheet that you’re trying to override, you’d need it in `$().css()`.

Comment: As the other comments have implied, this is just wrong. While the `style` attribute overrides all CSS which is applied without `!important`, it does not affect CSS which is applied with `!important`.

Comment: Not only is this incorrect, but OP asked HOW not if he needed