# can i add css with !important , only using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

hi i am using jquery

i want to add css color with `important property` to a label

i am currently trying it by

```
 jQuery(this).css('color','green !important')
```

with out using a class

like

```
label_class
{
    background-color:#f2f2f2 !important;
}
```

and  using like

```
jQuery(this).addClass('label_class');
```

can i use only jquery to do this , please help

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to include !important in jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986182/how-to-include-important-in-jquery)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes its not that hard, but you should try avoid using !important all the time.

```
$("#tabs").css("cssText", "height: 650px !important;");
```

Heres a link to similar question [How to include !important in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986182/how-to-include-important-in-jquery)

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 3):

You should never need to do this. The !important flag indicates that the style should take precedence. With jQuery, you are applying the style inline to the element and therefore it already has the highest precedence.

Note that if you are using `!important`, you are probably doing something wrong. Consider restructuring your CSS selectors to ensure you don't need it.