# how use !important in jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, function, download

```
$("#PtmIframe").contents().find("#header .sf-menu > li.sfHover > a, #header .sf-menu > li > a:hover, #header .sf-menu > li.sfHoverForce > a").css('background',"#"+HIhovcolor.!importanted).addClass("active");
        localStorage.setItem("HIhovcolor", HIhovcolor);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to include !important in jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986182/how-to-include-important-in-jquery)

Answer (score 2):

General Syntax

```
jQuery.style(name, value, priority);
```

so use

```
$("#tabs").style('background', "#"+HIhovcolor, 'important');
```

[**adding-css-rules-with-important-using-jquery**](http://aramk.com/blog/2012/01/17/adding-css-rules-with-important-using-jquery/)

Comment: Can you provide the link to official document as I have never used it.

Comment: @Satpal above link i provided may help you and i have also seen this type of an answer here too http://stackoverflow.com/a/8894528/2967572

Answer (score 1):

i think this will help you

```
$("#tabs").css("cssText", "height: 650px !important;");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#PtmIframe").contents().find("#header .sf-menu > li.sfHover > a, #header .sf-menu > li     > a:hover, #header .sf-menu > li.sfHoverForce > a").css('background',"#"+HIhovcolor.+" !importanted").addClass("active");
    localStorage.setItem("HIhovcolor", HIhovcolor);
```

Comment: Why two different answers? Can't you write both of them in one answer itself?

Comment: sorry that was my mistake

Answer (score 0):

As i see you don't need to have a `!important` css hack with jQuery's `.css()` method, this method adds an inline style to the dom node you target.
`!important` should be used in `.css` files to a specific css class where you want it to override the styling.

---

Your case:

```
$("#PtmIframe").contents().find("#header .sf-menu > li.sfHover > a, #header .sf-menu > li > a:hover, #header .sf-menu > li.sfHoverForce > a")
.css('background',"#"+HIhovcolor)
.addClass("active");
```

This line `.css('background',"#"+HIhovcolor)` would output something like this:

```
<li style='backgroung: #yourColorCode' class='active'>.....</li>
```

---

So i have to say that inline styling have much priority than the css class styling, then you should not have any issues with this. Yet you can do this:

```
.css('background', '#' + HIhovcolor + ' !important')
 //---------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^---concatenate it as string.
```