# jQuery - Cannot dynamically change height of textarea with CSS !important

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to change the height of my textarea. Zurb's Foundation has already defined a height of `5rem !important`.

Now, when I try to change my height using jQuery, it doesn't change. I tried:

```
$('textarea').height('500px')
$('textarea').css('height', '500px', 'important);
```

and nothing works. The CSS of any other property does change with `.css()`. What can I do?

Comment: Is the already defined style `5rem !important`
 an inline style ?

Comment: Don't see a problem:http://jsfiddle.net/U75uW/ Can you check if some other style definition is over ridding your jQuery style

Comment: @blunderboy, no it is defined in the foundation's css file.

Comment: `.css('height', '500px', '!important');` - missing quotes in important

Comment: @NikhilTalreja, your example doesn't have a predefined CSS! My problem is that when you do define the CSS, then it does not work

Comment: @ShaunakD, no you do not need the `!` when you use the jQuery: `.css(name, value, priority)`.

Comment: @Kousha, yes got it. I checked without `!`!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/U75uW/3/)**

You can use css - but it does not support `Priority` field.

Following is the correct syntax:

```
$('textarea').css('height','500px')
```

Or if you need `important`, you can use inline style or a class.

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/U75uW/4/)** : Add Class

```
.areaHeight{
    height : 500px !important;
}

$('textarea').addClass('areaHeight')
```

There are other not-so-viable options : **[cssText](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1986850/3639582)**

Answer (score 1):

If `5rem !important` is set as **inline style** then it has the **highest precedence** then **you can not override it by any CSS rule**. You have to **update the inline style** then. Try this:

```
$('textarea').get(0).style.setProperty('height','200px','important');
```

From the [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration)

> **CSSStyleDeclaration.setProperty()**
>
> No return. Example: styleObj.setProperty('color', 'red', 'important')

Update:

Please read this [Answer: Apply !important CSS style using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8894528/816213)
You will find really useful info there..

Happy Coding!!

Answer (score 0):

```
$('textarea').attr('style', 'height: 500px !important');
```

Comment: Alright this worked thanks! But why can't I just use `.css()`??

Comment: I won't prefer doing this because it will over-ride my entire inline style.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<textarea id="textareaid"> </textarea>
$('#textareaid').css('height', '500px');
```

Comment: Welcome to SO!! I see this is a new answer. Please try to read the existing answers and exact question. Your answer does not answer the OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

Try using anyone of these to set the height

```
Type:  1
 $("textareaid").height("600")

Type:  2
 $("textareaid").css("height","400px")
```

Make sure ur script is called after the dom element gets created