# jQuery .css not applying on parent container

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to apply an inline css using below statement.

```
$('.WarningCount').parent().css('margin-left', '-1.4% !important;');
```

But it doesn't work, it doesn't get applied only. I cannot see this style in the Developer console. I had to override the entire style to make it work.

```
$('.WarningCount').parent().attr('style', 'margin-left:-1.4% !important;');
```

Any reason what could be the real issue here.

Comment: Could you create [mcve] for us to see, we need the html also to even try to find the error, might also need the other css-rules that apply to the parent-element.

Comment: please post your html too

Comment: See the duplicate for a fix to the immediate issue. I would suggest you structure your CSS selectors to use selector precedence correctly instead, though. It's a more extensible fix.

Comment: I would suggest using classes like the JQuery Documentation says, `$('.WarningCount').parent().addClass('margin-left-added-class')`

Answer (score 1):

Taken from the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css2):

> Note: .css() ignores !important declarations. So, the statement $( "p"
>   ).css( "color", "red !important" ) does not turn the color of all
>   paragraphs in the page to red. It's strongly advised to use classes
>   instead; otherwise use a jQuery plugin.

Though, you can refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986182/how-to-include-important-in-jquery) and use cssText attribute

```
const target = $('.WarningCount').parent();
target.css('cssText', target.attr('style')+'margin-left: -1.4% !important;');
```

Comment: The OP states they've already done that. A much better solution would be to structure the  CSS rules properly so you don't need to use `!important` at all

Comment: `The OP states they've already done that` -> Done what?

Comment: Use the `css()` solution. The `parent().css()` example you show has the same problem as in the OP - the quote you even took from the docs explains why this won't work. Also, if you believe another question has the solution, please vote to close this as a duplicate. Don't add another answer to this question with a link as it stops the Roomba from deleting this question.

Comment: You're right. Let me fix

Comment: It makes more sense to just delete this

Comment: You're wrong. The question of the PO is `Any reason what could be the real issue here.`. The answer is in the jQuery documentation that I quoted.

Answer (score 0):

Use JSON format instead of comma format. Like this,

```
$(".WarningCount").parent().css({"margin-left": "-1.4%"});
```

Comment: This still will not work.

Answer (score 0):

```
$( '.WarningCount' ).parent().each(function () {
    this.style.setProperty( 'margin-left', '-1.4%', 'important' );
});
```

The `.setProperty` method of an element's style object or part of CSSStyleDeclaration enables you to pass a third argument which represents the priority. So, you're overriding `!important` with your own `!important` value.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/setProperty

Hope this clears any doubts regarding the same.

Comment: Please add a short explanation of your code.