# jQuery code not working with wordpress site

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

So im working on a site, a custom wp theme with a _s boilerplate, i've enqueue my styles and scripts which the browser picks up fine no errors;

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap-css', 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css' );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap-js', 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js', array(jquery), true);

    wp_enqueue_style( 'cbd-yums-style', get_stylesheet_uri() );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'cbd-yums-scripts', get_template_directory_uri(). '/js/scripts.js', array(), true );
```

[image: scripts.js is where my jquery code is]

scripts.js is where my jquery code is AND IM TRYING TO CHANGE THE TEXT COLOR OF MY MAIN NAVIGATION ITEMS  i tried this code believing it would work:

```
( function( $ ) {

    $('.primary-menu .menu-item').css('background-color', '#AED038');

} ) ( jQuery );
```

& the corresponding HTML

```
<nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation col-md-6 col-lg-6">
  <button class="menu-toggle" aria-controls="primary-menu" aria-expanded="false">Primary Menu</button>
  <div class="menu-header-menu-container">
    <ul id="primary-menu" class="menu nav-menu" aria-expanded="false">
      <li id="menu-item-44" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-44"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
      <li id="menu-item-45" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-45"><a href="#about">About</a></li>
      <li id="menu-item-46" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-46"><a href="#products">CBD Products</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>        
</nav>
```

But no change on browser reload, so i went back to w3schools to check my syntax. i modified the jquery css() example;
[image: and it seems my syntax is fine]

Can anybody see that i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Why didn't you added jQuery to your dependencies?
`    wp_enqueue_script( 'cbd-yums-scripts', get_template_directory_uri(). '/js/scripts.js', array('jquery'), true );`
And why isn't jquery a string in this --> `wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap-js', 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js', array(jquery), true);` ?

Comment: doesn't work, i tried : $('.primary-menu .menu-item').css('cssText', 'background-color: #AED038 !important;'); , i found the use of cssText here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986182/how-to-include-important-in-jquery

Comment: @SumeshTG no need to use `!important` - inline css has highest specificity weight, so use of !important is redundant.

Comment: primary-menu is an id not a class, use like #primary-menu not like .primary-menu

Answer (score 3):

you have to select ids with `#` prefix in jquery, in current situation call in id with `.` prefix that means class name, jquery is searching  class name `primary-menu`, since you dont have any element with class name `primary-menu`, the style is ignored.

the issue can be solved by change the query
`$('#primary-menu .menu-item').css('background-color', '#AED038');`

Comment: thanks you for pointing that out and i've even got my glasses on lol, but it still didn't work, 
   $('#primary-menu .menu-item').css('background-color', '#AED038'); am i right in saying that in theory this should 1. look for and element with ID 'primary-menu' 2. look for a child element with class 'menu-item' 3. change the elements background-color to #aed038.

Answer (score 0):

I FOUND THE PROBLEM!!
 1. i didn't have jQuery properly loaded as a dependency 
 2. I didn't make sure jQuery was written in not conflict mode

so i simply changed it to

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('#primary-menu .menu-item').css('background-color', '#AED038');
});
```

and in the functions.php where i have to enqueue scripts and styles

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'cbd-yums-scripts', get_template_directory_uri(). '/js/scripts.js', array( 'jquery' ), '20181025' ,true );
```

thank you everyone for helping me narrow down the problem

Answer (score -1):

*A page can't be manipulated safely until the document is "ready."* - http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Alter your code like this:

```
(function($) {

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#primary-menu .menu-item').css('background-color', '#AED038');

    });

})(jQuery);
```

Now the code will execute once the document is ready.

And as Hafeez Hamza pointed out: change `.primary-menu` to `#primary-menu`.

Comment: What? Shorthand for `$(document).ready(function() {` is `$(function() {`. Could you clarify?

Comment: From the first anwser referring to `(function($){` : *The code in your question has nothing to do with .ready(). Rather, it is an immediately-invoked function expression (IIFE) with the jQuery object as its argument.*

Comment: sort by votes - and even so, the problem isn't due to how they declared the `$(document)`

Comment: Ow yes that could be the problem, wordpress places the scripts tags in the head. See this JSfiddle demonstrating my point: https://jsfiddle.net/jrducf6v/3/ If you can refute that i will delete my answer.

Comment: you have a flawed test - jQuery/JavaScript is synchronous - it will take the last given values.. example 1: https://jsfiddle.net/hjxv26de/ works and example 2: https://jsfiddle.net/8ekwbpur/ works

Comment: No the test is valid, i targeted diffrent elements by id: `#menu-item-44`, `#menu-item-45` and `#menu-item-46` so that it would not override.The second JSfiddle only works because the `load type` is set to `on load`. I changed the load type of your JSfiddle and it does not work: https://jsfiddle.net/8ekwbpur/1/