# CSS give class or css to only selected element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have group of unordered list. I have create some function that make every list is clicked, it will run a JS Function. Now I want to add some css, if the list is clicked, its bg color will changed. My code so far:

```js
function getDealsTable(obj) {
        var tenor = obj.innerHTML;
        $(this).closest('li').css('background-color: rgba(86, 142, 175, 1) !important');
        $(this).closest('li').siblings('li').css('background-color: rgba(15, 86, 132, 1) !important');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class='tenors'>
    <li onclick='getDealsTable(this);'>12x</li>
    <li onclick='getDealsTable(this);'>24x</li>
    <li onclick='getDealsTable(this);'>36x</li>
    <li onclick='getDealsTable(this);'>48x</li>
</ul>
```

Unfortunately it doesn't works. I have tried to change it to a class, but still not working. Anyone can help me? Thanks

Comment: closest means traverse up the tree - you can't have a closest li unless it is a nested ul (as your click is bound to an li)

Comment: 'this' IS the li, so no need to do closest, try $(this).css('background-color: rgba(86, 142, 175, 1) !important');

Comment: already tried to only $(this) but still not working

Comment: What do want to actually achieve? Also with sibling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use `!important` with jQuery, you need to have 2 parameters. The first parameter is `cssText`, the second is the text you want to set as [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986182/how-to-include-important-in-jquery)

Example:

```
$('.selector').css('cssText', 'color: red !important;')
```

You can also create the click event using `on` directly in the javascript, no need to place it on the html element.

```js
$('ul.tenors > li').on('click', function() {
  // Reset all the li colors (must come first)
  $('ul.tenors > li').css('cssText','background-color: rgba(86, 142, 175, 1) !important;');
  // Set the color of the clicked li item (must come second)
  $(this).css('cssText', 'background-color: rgba(15, 86, 132, 1) !important;');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class='tenors'>
  <li>12x</li>
  <li>24x</li>
  <li>36x</li>
  <li>48x</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Perfect! But at your code, the color is reversed. But it's okay, I can handle it. Also thanks to remove that function to be just point it at its class. Thanks!

Comment: I added some comments to the js, just in case you need them.

Comment: Sure! Thanks for explanation... :)